# How to use GtkSocket in Windows OS?

Tags: gtk

New to Gtk. I tried to compile a GtkSocket example in c, but it gives error unknow type name 'GtkSocket'. 
Is it supported in Windows OS?
If not, is there any way I can embed gvim in a gtk+3 applicaton?

Also is there any link where can I know which Gtk feature is supported on which OS?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reference manual:

> The GtkPlug and GtkSocket widgets are now X11-specific, and you have
>   to include the gtk/gtkx.h header to use them.

Afaik, there is no list of features supported by which backend/os. For APIs difference, GtkSocket is pretty much the biggest difference. But there are several backend specific APIs, usually with a different namespace, such as x11/win32.. This is quite common with portable libraries.

I don't know a proper way to embed an application on win32. There are other stackoverflow questions about this, since this is not gtk specific. For example [QT How to embed an application into QT widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472840/qt-how-to-embed-an-application-into-qt-widget) that you could adapt to Gtk+ application.